# Господа верстальщики, главное меню "без таблиц", как сделать?

Tags: html, css

Господа верстальщики, вопрос вам, как сделать [Это](http://jsfiddle.net/8ECrE/) без использования: table-cell?

CMS выдает меню именно в таком формате:

```
<ul>
    <li>index</li>
    <li>navigation</li>
    <li>mobile</li>
    <li>gps map</li>
    <li>other</li>
</ul>
```

- нужно чтобы при добавлении\удалении пункта все "автоматически" сжималось\растягивалось как с таблицами, реально обойтись без table; table-cell?
- Так-ли принципиально отказываться от table; table-cell в данном случае?

Comment: Не принципиально если не сапортить IE 6,7

Элементарно посмотреть как и что хавают браузеры, и сделать свои выводы. Что использовать и что сапортить!



  [1]: http://htmlbook.ru/css/display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите на библиотеку polyfill [{display: table} для IE6 и IE7](http://tanalin.com/projects/display-table-htc/). Думаю наиболее простое решение. Принцип работы для IE < 8 заключается в замене элемента с `display: table-*` обычной таблицей автоматически.

Answer (score 0):

Меню я так понимаю горизонтальное? 
ul, li {
float: left
}
Без всякого табличного отображения. Не забыть отменить обтекание ul. Если он находится в nav, то просто задать 
nav {
overflow: hidden;
}